# what is meant by "[\x09-\x0d -~]" regular expression?

Tags: java, c, regex

Can any one please tell me what is meant by `[\x09-\x0d -~]` in the following signature. I am familiar with regular expressions, but this signature is in a C code, and I can not understand what is meant by this `x` and `~`, I am trying to make signatures and I am working in java, and I have seen this `x` and `~` many times on net, but i could not understand what does it mean. 
Are these regular expressions or these are hexadecimal value or something else? because i have not seen this neither in regular expressions nor in SIP messages.

```
^(invite|register|cancel|message|subscribe|notify) sip[\x09-\x0d -~]*sip/[0-2]\.[0-9]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[\x09-\x0d -~]` matches unicode code points represented by the hexadecimal numbers `\x09` up to `\x0d` and characters from space to `~`.

Basically, it matches all the basic ASCII characters that have a visual representation (using the term "visual" loosely here as you don't really see tabs and line feeds, but you get my point).

See this table http://www.asciitable.com/ for reference.

Comment: Shouldn't this match two ranges, \x09 up to \x0d and space up to ~ ?

Comment: Wow you're right. I completely let that slip by. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hey, don't feel bad. I completely missed that too. ;) [Deleted my answer because @Vache's is now correct.]